# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, parameters

what's the problem in my code ?
this is full of my connection code...
please help me what's the wrong in this code ?

```
 <?php
     define("Server", "localhost");//constant for connennection
     define("Username", "root");
     define("Password", "123456");
?>

 <?php    //  connection
  $conection=  mysql_connect(Server, Username, Password);
  if(!$conection)
          die("connection faild :".  mysql_error());

 $db_select=  mysql_select_db("widget",$conection);

  if (!$db_select) {
             die("selection faild :".mysql_error());   
         }
 ?>
 <?php

 function conform_query($result){

         if (!$result) {
                      die("query failed :".mysql_error()); }
 }
    function get_subject_by_id($subject_id) {
          global $conection;
      $query = "SELECT * ";//data base query
      $query .= "FROM subject ";
      $query .= "WHERE id= " . $subject_id ." ";
      $query .= "LIMIT 1";
      $result_set = mysql_query($query, $conection);

      conform_query($result_set);

      // REMEMBER:
      // if no rows are returned, fetch_array will return false
       if ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))   {
           return $subject;
       } 
           else {
          return NULL;
       }
}
?>
```

I try to run this but every time has error what should I do. I couldn't find my mistake.

Comment: where is your database connection configuration? Please update your answer with it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have not initialized your connection.

You should add

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
```

and only after that do

```
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
    $query .= "WHERE id=" . $subject_id ." ";
```

to

```
    $query .= "WHERE id='" . $subject_id ."' ";
```

Here I am assuming that `$conection` has the value of `mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);` and you have selected the database using `mysql_select_db($database)`. Go through the following manuals:

1. [mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
2. [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)