# PHP MySQL Query Insert consistent error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// php script for adding data from mysql database
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ip = $_GET['ip']; //for debugging sake, will be POST from Ajax
$key = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5); //random referral ID - will implement exist analysis
echo $ip; //debugging
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = user;
$dbpass = 'pass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $conn);
$tbl_name = "refs";
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(ip, key)VALUES('frfr', 'grgr')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
```

I'm not sure if it's my Digital Ocean server or what, but the only syntax my PhpMyAdmin will accept as a query is as `INSERT INTO`refs`(`ip`,`key`) VALUES ("insert","432")`
with the double quoted values. I cannot seem to get this implemented in the PHP without getting a flat out error or an Unknown column in 'field list' error.

Similar questions suggest junk non-printable characters from copy-paste, however I've retyped my code within the editor. Thanks for all the help

I'm creating a basic referral system by the way, storing requested IP's in 'refs' table with a key, or id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346209/unknown-column-in-field-list-error-on-mysql-update-query

Comment: wow, you using this on a live server?

Comment: You are missing a space before VALUES.

Comment: I would advice you to use mysqli, not mysql functions

Comment: If you want to use php variable then use php valriable without quotes or you can write like `values ('".$ip."','".$key."')`

Comment: $dbuser = 'user'; update this

Answer (score 3):

`key` is a reserve word and thus needs to be escaped using backtique. Along with that you have spacing issue as well. Your query should looks like below

```
INSERT INTO refs(ip,`key`) VALUES ('insert','432')
```

Never use a reserve word as column or table name. if in doubt, then escape all the columns present in query.

Start referring [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)  for more inforamtion. It's way easier than posting it as question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, this code is still giving me an error. I tried changing the "key" column to id and trying with and without the ` but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The error in my log is [13-Dec-2016 10:55:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/username/public_html/newref.php on line 21

Comment: @user3026679 that is because you're using mysql and not mysqli. therefore, you don't need to assign the connection to the query. `mysql_query($sql,$con)` => `mysql_query($sql)` ALSO: `$con` is not defined... you possibly made a typo there, should have been `$conn`, if necessary.

Comment: @user3026679, that's a different issue now and again search that error message in google or in stackoverflow. You will get thousands of example like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142689/warning-mysql-query-expects-parameter-2-to-be-resource

Comment: @user3026679, and a final piece of suggestion: start putting a bit of effort than just asking a question. that way you will learn a lot.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Hallur's, Rahul Dambare's, and of course Rahul's answers helped solve the issue.

Comment: @user3026679 please mark this answer as an accepted answer so that this question will be marked as solved.